# Excel 2010, changing on its own

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have defined several names in a worksheet.Eg \d1 for John Smith.John is typed in cell a1 and Smith is typed in cell b1.When I enter the formula "=\d1"in a different cell eg in d4 I don't get the name in d4 and d5.The formula works for a single cell but does not work for a range of cells.Please help.

Comment: If you've set a defined name equal to "John Smith", then Excel will not split up the name into two cells when you enter it (whether you enter it into a single cell or into two cells as an array formula). But perhaps I am misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the formula in cell D4 and paste it into cells A4 and B4. The cell reference will automatically adjust to =A1 and =B1.

Why are you using a \ sign in the reference? This is Excel. Lotus123 is dead!!